# Why does my sql logic fail first time it runs but not second time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this sql:

```
SELECT
    sa.answertext
FROM dbo.tblsurveyanswer sa
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblsurvey s
                ON s.surveyid = sa.surveyid
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblquestion q
                ON q.questionid = sa.questionid
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblshqscriteria c
                ON c.shqscriteriaid = q.shqscriteriaid
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblshqsdescription d
                ON d.shqsdescriptionid = q.shqsdescriptionid
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblrepairpercentage rp
                ON rp.repairpercentageid = sa.repairpercentageid
WHERE 
(c.shqscriteria = 'qwerty')
OR 
(c.shqscriteria = 'zxcvb' AND ISNUMERIC(sa.answertext) = 1 AND CAST(sa.answertext AS float) < 5)
```

First time I execute it fails with "Error converting data type varchar to float."
Second time* I execute it succeeds - returning no rows because there are no 'qwerty'  or 'zxcvb' shqscriteria

*actually sometimes I have to hit execute up to 8 times before I get the failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not using aggregates, you should be able to rely on CASE's order of execution:

```
WHERE
...
OR
(
  c.shqscriteria = 'zxcvb' 
  AND 5 > CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(sa.answertext) = 1      
    THEN CAST(sa.answertext AS float) 
    ELSE 6 
  END
)
```

Note however that `ISNUMERIC(col) = 1` does not always mean that `col` is eligible to be converted to a *specific* numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

The order in which predicates are evaluated in SQL Server is not guaranteed (and certainly not guaranteed to be from left to right).

So:

```
c.shqscriteria = 'zxcvb' AND ISNUMERIC(sa.answertext) = 1 AND CAST(sa.answertext AS float) < 5
```

It may attempt the `CAST` operation on a value for which `ISNUMERIC()` returns 0. The actual order in which the predicates are evaluated can vary for many different reasons - as you've discovered, the slightest thing can change it.

Also, `ISNUMERIC` is a mostly useless function. `CAST('£' as float)` will fail, but `ISNUMERIC('£')` is `1`. It answers the question no-one has ever asked - "Can I convert this string into even just *one* of the numeric datatypes (I don't care which one)?"

The way to resolve this kind of issue is to split your query into two parts - the first of which selects appropriate data for conversion and stores the values in a (temp table/table variable), the second part actually performs the conversion. Or if you're on SQL Server 2012 or later, look into the [`TRY_` conversion functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx):

```
c.shqscriteria = 'zxcvb' AND TRY_CAST(sa.answertext AS float) < 5
```

Comment: Thanks Damien. I wanted to create a view using the query so I tried to select the appropriate data as an inner query, but still got the problem. Is there any way to do this in sql server 2008 without the table variable?

Comment: @Colin - Many have *tried* to come up with ways to "guarantee" the order of evaluation, but I'm not aware of any that have produced a 100% bomb-proof method. Instead of a view, you may be able to do the two steps in a table-valued function.

Comment: Well, I didn't mention that I also wanted to materialise the view. The CASE technique that Aaron has suggested appears to work. Are you saying it's not bomb-proof for ensuring an order of execution then?(let's say we ignore the fact that ISNUMERIC is not much good for now)